# how do I get rid of the links and all the links related menu items on the admin ui?

Tags: links, admin-menu

Since I won't be using the built-in links feature of wordpress, I see no reason in keeping its related menu items on the admin ui causing nothing but clutter.

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove entire admin menu?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52099/how-to-remove-entire-admin-menu)

Comment: @Chris_O "possible duplicate" hits the nail on its head. That's only true if the answer would be the _exact_ same, which isn't in this case (you couldn't know that when commenting this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme's *functions.php*:

```
function wpse52464_admin_ui_fixes() {
    remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpse52464_admin_ui_fixes');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is changed in WP 3.5 - "links" will be moved to a core plugin (like "Akismet" and "Hello Dolly") and be deactivated by default.