# Remove "posts" from admin but show a custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, admin-menu

After checking out:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page,
I successfully use the following code to hide some stuff from the menu:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('link-manager.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');  
}
```

However both the "posts page" and a custom post types page seems to run on `/wp-admin/edit.php`.

So I'm looking for a way to *hide* the posts menubar but still show the menu for a custom post type I've added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing this [search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2bremove_menu_page%20%2bpost_type&submit=search), I've found [this fine answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52151/12615) by Chris_O. There's even a jQuery solution I proposed there.

Anyway, the function `remove_menu_page('edit.php');` only removes the Posts menu.

But, as we learn from Chris answer, **`remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=athletes');`** removes the Custom Post Type menu.

To really block access to the URL, as we're merely hiding the menu item, check the following Q&A: [Blocking Administrative Access to Authors and Subcribers?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53714/12615)

Comment: Of course, `athletes` is the name of my Custom Post Type... Adjust as necessary.

Comment: It works! cool! Thanks for showing how I could've searched!

Comment: Can I choose two right answers?

Comment: @Alisso No. You can only choose one. Since both show the same solution in part, you might want to choose one has the all (or most) the necessary details you need. :)

Comment: This function doesn't remove anything, it merely hides it.

Comment: @Piet, OP titles the questions as "remove", ends asking about "hiding", but none of this is about "blocking" access, I'll add a reference for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried and `remove_menu_page('edit.php');` only removes the Posts Top Level Menu.

All my other custom post types (and I have a lot) still work fine. I have a feeling this is because it does a direct lookup of the exactly slug, not the basename of the file.