# Custom Admin Menu Order

Tags: menus, customization, admin, order

I have a simple solution in my functions.php for reordering the admin menu.  Here it is:

```
// Admin menu - reorder
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord){
  if (!$menu_ord) return true;
  return array(
    'index.php', // Dashboard
    'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
    'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', // WooCommerce
    'edit.php?post_type=product', // Products
    'gf_edit_forms', // Forms
    'upload.php', // Media
    'separator1', // First separator
    'separator2', // Second separator
    'separator-last', // Last separator
    'users.php', // Users
    'themes.php', // Appearance
    'options-general.php', // Settings
    'plugins.php', // Plugins
    'tools.php', // Tools
    'itsec', // Security
    'edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group', // Custom Fields
    'edit.php?post_type=cptm' // Post types
  );
}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

This works just fine, except this one item does not work:

```
'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', // WooCommerce
```

It just shows up at the bottom of the menu, everything I try to do to make it show up in the proper order fails.  I believe the issue is the post_type name **shop_order**.  It's the underscore that I think is making it fail.

Any thoughts on why that might be?  Please don't say to use a plugin as the goal of this is to avoid using additional plugins.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual slug for the WooCommerce menu item is 'woocommerce'.

So if you replace:

```
'edit.php?post_type=shop_order', // WooCommerce
```

with:

```
'woocommerce', // WooCommerce
```

the above code will work.

I found a handy function that will display all the items in the menu array at [How to remove admin menu pages inserted by plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136058/how-to-remove-admin-menu-pages-inserted-by-plugins).

Here is the function (from the above link) that I use when reordering menu items:

```
function my_debug_admin_menu() {
    echo '<pre style="margin-left:200px;">' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_debug_admin_menu' );
```

Comment: Thank you!  It worked, and thank you for the other info as well.  I'm sure I'll use that in the future.