# Remove Duplicator plugin from admin menu if not an administrator

Tags: plugins, customization, admin

I'm having a bit of trouble removing the menu item added by the Duplicator plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) from the admin menu if the user is not an administrator.

I am able to remove non-plugin items successfully by using the following code:

```
function jitb_remove_admin_menu_items() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $remove_menu_items = array( __( 'Comments' ), __( 'Links' ), __( 'Posts' ), __( 'Media' ), __( 'Users' ), __( 'Tools' ), __( 'Settings' ), __( 'Profile' ), __( 'Testimonials' ), __( 'Appearance' ), __( 'Portfolio' ), __( 'Duplicator' ) );
        global $menu;
        end ( $menu );
        while ( prev( $menu ) ) {
            $item = explode( ' ',$menu[key( $menu )][0] );
            if( in_array( $item[0] != NULL?$item[0]:"" , $remove_menu_items ) ){
                unset( $menu[key( $menu)] );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'jitb_remove_admin_menu_items' );
```

but this isn't working for the Duplicator plugin menu item.

I have also had a look at the Duplicator plugin code, and it is showing the menu item being set up with this code:

```
function duplicator_menu() {
    $wpfront_caps_translator = 'wpfront_user_role_editor_duplicator_translate_capability';

    //Main Menu
    $perms = 'export';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $main_menu = add_menu_page('Duplicator Plugin', 'Duplicator', $perms, 'duplicator', 'duplicator_get_menu', plugins_url('duplicator/assets/img/create.png'));

    $perms = 'export';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $page_packages = add_submenu_page('duplicator', __('Packages', 'wpduplicator'), __('Packages', 'wpduplicator'), $perms, 'duplicator', 'duplicator_get_menu');

    $perms = 'manage_options';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $page_settings = add_submenu_page('duplicator', __('Settings', 'wpduplicator'), __('Settings', 'wpduplicator'), $perms, 'duplicator-settings', 'duplicator_get_menu');

    $perms = 'manage_options';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $page_tools = add_submenu_page('duplicator', __('Tools', 'wpduplicator'), __('Tools', 'wpduplicator'), $perms, 'duplicator-tools', 'duplicator_get_menu');

    $perms = 'read';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $page_help = add_submenu_page('duplicator', __('Help', 'wpduplicator'), __('Help', 'wpduplicator'), $perms, 'duplicator-help', 'duplicator_get_menu');

    $perms = 'read';
    $perms = apply_filters($wpfront_caps_translator, $perms);
    $page_about = add_submenu_page('duplicator', __('About', 'wpduplicator'), __('About', 'wpduplicator'), $perms, 'duplicator-about', 'duplicator_get_menu');

    //Apply Scripts
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_packages, 'duplicator_scripts');
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_settings, 'duplicator_scripts');
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_help, 'duplicator_scripts');
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_tools, 'duplicator_scripts');
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page_about, 'duplicator_scripts');

    //Apply Styles
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page_packages, 'duplicator_styles');
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page_settings, 'duplicator_styles');
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page_help, 'duplicator_styles');
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page_tools, 'duplicator_styles');
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page_about, 'duplicator_styles');
}
```

however, adding the title 'Duplicator' to my  jitb_remove_admin_menu_items function doesn't remove the menu item.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research, I have found a way to do this from this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136064/54989

Rather than using [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) as I had done previously, [remove_menu_page works](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) for Duplicator:

```
remove_menu_page( 'duplicator' );
```

so my complete code now looks like:

```
function jitb_remove_admin_menu_items() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        $remove_menu_items = array( __( 'Comments' ), __( 'Links' ), __( 'Posts' ), __( 'Media' ), __( 'Users' ), __( 'Tools' ), __( 'Settings' ), __( 'Profile' ), __( 'Testimonials' ), __( 'Appearance' ), __( 'Portfolio' ),  __( 'Products' ), __( 'Orders' ), __( 'Coupons' ) );
        global $menu;
        end ( $menu );
        while ( prev( $menu ) ) {
            $item = explode( ' ',$menu[key( $menu )][0] );
            if( in_array( $item[0] != NULL?$item[0]:"" , $remove_menu_items ) ){
                unset( $menu[key( $menu)] );
            }
        }
        remove_menu_page( 'duplicator' );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'jitb_remove_admin_menu_items' );
```