# Remove add news page and posts from menu

Tags: customization, sub-menu

I want remove add news page and posts from left menu
I try to use `remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'post-new.php');` but it only remove add news from posts, I need to remove add news from pages too.

Comment: Please check this answer [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136058/how-to-remove-admin-menu-pages-inserted-by-plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136058/how-to-remove-admin-menu-pages-inserted-by-plugins)